# Django urls.py not updating to include heroku url?

Tags: django, heroku, django-urls

I am trying to deploy my Django app on Heroku and I am following the tutorial but when I go and try to open the website with:

```
heroku open
```

I receive the error :

```
Request URL:    http://nameless-dawn-7713.herokuapp.com/
Using the URLconf defined in crunchWeb.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^crunchApp/results$
^crunchApp/contact$
^admin/

The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

Even though before running " heroku open" my URLs.py file looks like this (saved) :

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('crunchApp.views',


url(r'^crunchApp/results$', 'results'),
url(r'^http://nameless-dawn-7713.herokuapp.com/$', 'contact'),
url(r'^crunchApp/contact$', 'contact'),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

)

I think I might have to change the urls.py before the command:

```
git commit -m "my django app"
```

but I dont know the URL that it will need until the command:

```
heroku create
```

Any ideas of what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have `url(r'^http://nameless-dawn-7713.herokuapp.com/$', 'contact')` in your urls file ? In fact, these URLs should be relative to your application, and you should not update this file before uploading to Heroku (if it works locally, it should work on Heroku without any change to this file).

If you want to connect the contact view to your base URL (http://nameless-dawn-7713.herokuapp.com/), you should use something like:

```
url(r'^$', 'contact')
```

Hope this helps !